# FM in Android application in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I have got a problem in FM application.
The error is in the code below:

```
String tmp=((editText)findViewById(R.id.editText1)).getText().toString();
```

The error says that editText cannot be resolved to a type.
What does it mean and how to solve it?

Comment: The class name is `EditText`, and Java is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Below Line

```
EditText mEdttxt1=((EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1));
String tmp= mEdttxt1.getText().toString();
```

instead of

```
String tmp=((editText)findViewById(R.id.editText1)).getText().toString();
```